# How to install Gnome specific version on Arch

Tags: linux, ubuntu, archlinux, gnome

I am using Arch with GNOME 41.2 and want to use GNOME 3.38.3 how can I install it, I checked everywhere but I am unable to find any installation guide that tells how to install any specific version of GNOME. I am new to Linux and I've spent my 5 hours searching for this please help me out.

Comment: ? Build gnome from source ? .............. Example release version with gnome-desktop 3.38.3 : Mageia 8 http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/mageia/distrib/8/x86_64/media/core/release/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.